# Split the string from first Upper case letter

Tags: java, string, split, char, character

I want to extract the file name and timestamp from this text using java

invoice_12890.pdfAPR 10, 2019 8:33:16 AM

Expect

- invoice_12890.pdf
- APR 10, 2019 8:33:16 AM

Comment: `split("(?<=\\p{Ll})(?=\\p{Lu})")` i.e. split on the zero-width space between a lowercase letter and an uppercase letter.

Comment: Check for the first UPPERCASE character.

Comment: observed that sometimes file name starts with UPPERCASE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
boolean hadDot=false;//this makes sure we don't split before finding the file extension
String file="",date="";
for(int i=0;i<text.length();i++){
  if(text.charAt(i)=='.'){
    hadDot=true;
    continue;
  }
  if(hadDot&&Character.isUpperCase(text.charAt(i))){
    file=text.substring(0,i);
    date=text.substring(i);
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: if(hadDot&&Character.isUpperCase(text.charAt(i))) this condition always returns false

Comment: Fixed the issue in my answer; I used break instead of continue

Comment: Your logic was great to solve this. I wish I become a programmer like you.

Comment: THIS SLOVED MY PROBLEM, THANKS